# Reading characters from a stream up to whitespace using isspace in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that takes a stream as an argument and reads from that stream and reads in the contents of the file up to the first whitespace as defined by the isspace function, and then uses the strtok function to parse the string.  I'm not sure how to start it though with which function to read a line and ignore the whitespace.  I know fgetc and getc only read one character at a time, and looking up the fscanf reference, will that work?  Or does that only find items in your stream according to the format specifiers %s?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### C Answer

The **[fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) s conversion** will match a sequence of non-white-space characters.  The input string stops at white space (as defined by `isspace`) or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.  Note that there must be enough space in the provided buffer or it may be overflowed by long input.

```
FILE *fp;
char cstr[128];

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

while (!feof(fp))
{    
    fscanf(fp, "%s", cstr);
    ...
}
```

#### Original C Answer

The [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) function will allow you to read in the file one line at a time, but you will still need to check each character with `isspace`.

Since `isspace` may include space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v') in its check for white-space characters, your best bet may be to read one character at a time in a loop using the [fgetc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) function. Note that if the integer value returned by [fgetc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) is stored into a variable of type char and then compared against the integer constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed, because sign-extension of a variable of type char on widening to integer is implementation-defined.

```
FILE *fp;
int c;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if (isspace(c))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Original C++ Answer

The [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) method will allow you to read in one line at a time and optionally specify the delimiter (default is '/n').

Since `isspace` may include space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v') in its check for white-space characters, your best bet may be to read one character at a time in a loop using the [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) method.

```
char c;
string str;
ifstream file("test.txt",ios::in);
while (file.get(c)) 
{
    if (isspace((unsigned char)c))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        str.push_back(c);
    }

    file.peek();
    if (file.eof())
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

<sub>Note: Error checking was omitted from the all of the above code for simplicity.</sub>

Comment: (BTW, this answer originally made sense since the question was originally tagged as C++, but since the question title says C and since the question body references only C functions, I've retagged the question.)

Comment: You should prevent the buffer overflows correctly. And never store the result of `fgetc()` in a `char` variable. Don't use `feof` for checking whether you are _at the end of the file_, since `feof` is for checking whether you _have already tried to read beyond the end of file_. Don't use `file.eof` in C++ either. I hope the `c` in the C++ example is not declared as `char`, since that would invoke _undefined behavior_ (see the ctype.h documentation).

Comment: @RolandIllig, I appreciate the constructive criticisms. Rather than simply point out what not to do, feel free edit and correct the examples for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @jschmier My reason for not correcting these mistakes on my own is that you might not notice the change, which in turn means that you will continue to give these wrong answers. And that would not benefit the community at all.

Comment: @RolandIllig, do you still have serious issues with this sample code now that I've attempted to address your concerns?

Comment: There is one remaining issue: the buffer overflow. There will be people copying the code without reading a single of the surrounding words, so it doesn't help to write warnings around the code. The code itself has to be solid.

Answer (score 2):

To read an entire line at a time, you generally should use `fgets`.  Some care is needed in case a line in the stream is longer than your buffer, the leftover will remain in the stream, which might not be what you want. (If you want to ignore the rest of the line, you can use `fgets` followed by `fscanf` as described at http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html.)

If you want to read in an entire line without worrying about a buffer size, you may wish to look into [Chuck Falconer's `ggets` function](http://www.taenarum.com/software/ggets/) which dynamically allocates a buffer for you (this does mean that you are responsible for freeing it).

Answer (score 1):

well although getc/fgetc only retrieve 1 character at a time, you can put them into a loop right ?:)